# Is Traupman's "Conversational Latin for Oral Proficiency" of good latinity?

Tags: contemporary-latin, modern-life, book

I am currently studying Latin and a friend has recommended Traupman's "Conversational Latin for Oral Proficiency" book.

Can I trust that the vocabulary within this book is accurate, or should I be concerned about learning incorrect Latin?

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen this book myself, but this review in an academic journal might be of interest to you:

https://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/1996/1996.12.12/

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting review of the first edition

Comment: It seems like they are up to 4th edition now; I wonder if they improved upon some of the criticisms of the first edition.